# Why copy of a member is returned rather than reference?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) member of an object which is lvalue is also an lvalue:

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:

> a.m, the member of object expression, except where m is a member enumerator or a non-static member function, or where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of object type;

Consider an example program with a custom class `Test` which is only a wrapper on `int` with additional prints in relevant places. In addition, there is a standalone function `get` which takes universal reference to `T` and returns its member using `decltype(auto)` rules.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test 
    {
        int member;
        explicit Test(int member): member(member) { std::cout << "Ctor" << std::endl; }
        Test(const Test& other): member(other.member) { std::cout << "Copy ctor" << std::endl; }
        Test(Test&& other) noexcept: member(other.member) { std::cout << "Move ctor" << std::endl; }
        Test& operator=(const Test& other) { member = other.member; std::cout << "Copy =" << std::endl; return *this; }
        Test& operator=(Test&& other) { member = other.member; std::cout << "Move =" << std::endl; return *this; }
        ~Test() { std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl; }
    };
    
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) get(T&& obj)
    {   
        std::cout << "Is obj lvalue ref? " << std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::forward<T>(obj))> << std::endl;
        return std::forward<T>(obj).member;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        Test test{1234};
        auto&& ret = get(test);
        ret = 5678;
        std::cout << "test.member is equal to " << test.member << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

To my understanding `decltype(auto)` deduces the type of an expression as follows:

1. For a `prvalue` it yields its type
2. For an `lvalue` it yields reference
3. For an `xvalue` it yields rvalue reference

But the output of the program is as follows:

```
Ctor
Is obj lvalue ref? 1
test.member is equal to 1234
Dtor
```

Assignment `ret = 5678` inside the main function does not change the value of the member inside the `test` object so the copy has to be done. Looks my understanding is not correct.

Comment: `decltype` has a special case when the argument is an unparenthesized variable name or *class member access*. Then it returns the type the variable was declared with, regardless of value categories.

Comment: `return (...);` should fix this.